# Как сместить элементы треугольного массива к другому краю?

Tags: java, массивы

У меня получилось сделать "рваный" массив в двух видах: обычный треугольник и перевернутый. Однако не могу сообразить, как сдвинуть элементы к другому краю. 
То есть, как сделать так, чтобы элементы были выстроены таким образом:

1-й вариант:

```
             0 
           1 2 
         3 4 5 
       6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14
```

2-й вариант:

```
0 1 2 3 4 
  5 6 7 8 
  9 10 11 
    12 13 
       14
```

Моя программа:
[Полный код программы](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ae860fadf49ef4b90ffa4ef2700361fd)

```
int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
            arr[i][j] = count++;
        }
```

Результат:

```
0 
1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14
```

Перевернутый треугольник:

```
    int[][]arr = new int[lines][];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        arr[i] = new int[lines - i];
    }
```

Результат:

```
0 1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
9 10 11 
12 13 
14
```

Comment: Вы привели два идентичных участка кода и утверждаете что они делают различные вещи. Ваш код лишь заполняет массив последовательностью чисел от 0 до `arr.length * arr[i].length`, ничего не переставляет в нем и не выводит результат никуда.

Comment: `arr[i][arr[i].length - 1- j] = count++;` так хотите?

Comment: Да, прошу прощение, не правильно напечатал.

Comment: исправьте код в вопросе так, чтобы было понятно что вы сделали и что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Исправил согласно Вашим поправкам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для вывода массива в консоль, отформатируйте строки с помощью команды `String.format` или  `System.out.printf` просто дополняя пробелами перед самим числом, например `System.out.printf("%4d", 15);` выведет `"  15"`, 4 символа, где первые 2 из 4 пробелы.
В Вашем коде исправил только вывод в консоль:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print ("Введите размер треугольного правого массива  ");
    triangle2(new Scanner(System.in).nextInt());
    System.out.print("Введите размер перевернутого правого массива  ");
    revTriangle2(new Scanner(System.in).nextInt());
}

static int[][] triangle2(int lines) {
    int[][] arr = new int[lines][];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int[i + 1];
    }
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = count++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        String str = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            str += String.format("%3d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        String format = "%" + lines * 3 + "s"; 
        System.out.printf(format, str);
        System.out.println();
    }
    return arr;
}

static int[][] revTriangle2(int lines){
    int[][]arr = new int[lines][];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        arr[i] = new int[lines - i];
    }

    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
            arr[i][j] = count++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        String str = "";
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
            str += String.format("%3d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        String format = "%" + lines * 3 + "s"; 
        System.out.printf(format, str);
        System.out.println();
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Результат в консоли:

```
Введите размер треугольного правого массива  5
              0
           1  2
        3  4  5
     6  7  8  9
 10 11 12 13 14
Введите размер перевернутого правого массива  5
  0  1  2  3  4
     5  6  7  8
        9 10 11
          12 13
             14
```